# Deploy plotly dash dashboard on a different windows server

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Would like to find out, is it possible to deploy Plotly Dash App dashboard  on a different windows server?
So as users can access through the server IP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify arguments for the Werkzeug server:

```
app.run_server(host="<ipaddress>")
```

If you're talking about deployment though I would consider using Waitress, Gunicorn or uWSGI (some discussion [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/production-and-development-enviroments/21348))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy Dash dashboard on windows server, but you have to embedded the Dash dashboard into Flask web framework with WSGI file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30068936)