# How to access a Plotly-Dash app server via LAN

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a Plotly-Dash app which is running perfectly fine under `localhost:8050` or `127.0.0.1:8050`.

Question is: how can I access this app server from another computer in the same LAN?

So far, I've tried to access `http://x.y.z.w/8050` with `x.y.z.w` being the LAN IP address of the server (ping goes ok). All I get is:

> ```
> This site can’t be reached
> x.y.z.w refused to connect.
> ```

Same when I try to access the server from the server computer itself, but using LAN IP instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. ping is fine.

---

On a note, the server computer (my laptop) is connected to the company network via VPN, but I don't think this would change anything, since that's the whole purpose of VPN. Then I remote desktop to a computer at the office and try to access back my server.

Comment: Please see the answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652046/deploy-plotly-dash-dashboard-on-a-different-windows-server/61673606#61673606)

Comment: Having you tried hosting under `0.0.0.0`? Either specifying it with `host` parameter in the `run_server` call or if you use gunicorn with the `bind` parameter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your app.py currently should have something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Try replacing this with `app.run_server(host= '0.0.0.0',debug=False)`
Now on the LAN browser, you should be able to access with the ip address of the server that you are running the dash app.

Also, you may want to check which port is used by this server for broadcast.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you specify `host='0.0.0.0` your application server would only listen to `127.0.0.1` which is `localhost`. When you specify `0.0.0.0` it means *listen on all computer interfaces* including your LAN one.

If you need share an application running on your local laptop externally over the internet and restrict access to just specific individuals, check out [this sample project](https://github.com/gwrun/tutorials/tree/main/plotly-dash/docker-compose) and tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Adding host=0.0.0.0 makes the app available to access from LAN

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```